# Can't bind to ngModel even though I'm importing FormsModule & syntax appears correct

Tags: angular, binding, ngmodel, two-way-binding

My problems started with an app exercise I was doing in Spring Boot and Angular. I discovered I couldn't bind to ngModel, ngClass, and a few other things. So I've worked my way to the very basics and tried a simple exercise from the book Angular Development with TypeScript, 2nd Ed. When I couldn't get rid of the error, I copied the book's code from GitHub, and I still get the error. Here is the code:

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input type="text"
        placeholder="Enter shipping address"
        [(ngModel)]="shippingAddress">
    <button (click)="shippingAddress='123 Main Street'">Set 
    Default Address</button>
    <p>The shipping address is {{ shippingAddress }}</p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  shippingAddress: string;
}
```

As you can see, FormsModule is imported, and the syntax of [(ngModel)] is correct, yet VS Code STILL shows an error of "Can't bind to ngModel because it isn't a known property of input."

I'm hoping that if you all can help me figure out the problem here then the answer will work with the Spring Boot/Angular exercise I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with VS code. Sometimes closing VSCode and opening again helps in these issues.

I tried same example on stackblitz and it is working for me
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vaeac1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Closing and opening didn't help, but your suggestion prompted me to look at other things in VS Code also. I disabled the Angular Language Services extension that I had added and voila! the errors were gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a name attribute for input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a name attribute to your input, because defining a name is required in order to use ngModel.
check the doc for more details:
[Building a template-driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms#!#ngModel)